# Empty data in response with axios and vuex

Tags: axios, vuex

When I send this patch request with axios, the backend receives the data, but **response.data** comes back empty. Please and thanks!

```
// ACTION IN VUEX STORE
async updateMe({ commit }, payload) {
  let id = localStorage.getItem('userId');
  let user = { name: payload.name, email: payload.email, id: id };
  try {
    const response = await axios.patch(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/updateMe`,
      user
    );
    commit('setUpdatedUser', response.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

// CONTROLLER
exports.updateMe = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.body.id,
    {
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email
    },
    { new: true, runValidators: true }
  );
  res.status(204).json({ data: updatedUser });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

204 is a No Content response code.